# How and When to Execute PRAGMA statement in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite. I just wonder how and when to execute a PRAGMA statment in sqlite.

For example, I want to execute:

```
PRAGMA schema.journal_mode = OFF;
```

Based on the document at https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode , I guess I should execute it after sqlite3_open() and before creating any tables. Therefore, I just invoke sqlite3_prepare_v2() and sqlite3_step() to execute the above PRAGMA, in order to improve the performance of database operations. However, after the PRAGMA statement, it seems nothing changed and the performance is not improved.

In such a case, how can I know whether the PRAGMA statement is executed and take effects?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the literal word "schema"? It should be "main" or the name of another attached database (or just leave it off).

Comment: Actually I do not use schema at all, my statement is PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the Pragma's will return the set value, additionally by just using the Pragma, without a parameter will return the current value (in some cases only this latter will return status/current value).

`PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF` will return a result of off.
`PRAGMA journal_mode` will return the current value without affecting it.

So just act as if it's a query, the column name in the result set will in many cases be the same as the pragma being actioned. Those that return multiple columns such as database_list will return columns specific to the pragma.

e.g.

```
PRAGMA journal_mode;
PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;
PRAGMA journal_mode;
PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE;
PRAGMA journal_mode;
```

results in :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there other ways to verify if the journal is off or not? For example, SQLite will save the log in a specific dir with a specific name, then I can check the existence of that log file to confirm that the journal is off or not.

Comment: Not reliably because the journal file does not have to exist as DELETE is the default, so it's non-existence doesn't necessarily mean that it is Off. [Temporary Files Used By SQLite (**see 2.1**)](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)

Comment: When I use "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;", the statement does NOT return any result. How can I know the parameter is set properly?

Comment: I think both "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;" and "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;" should be executed after the database is opened and before the tables are created, is that correct?

Comment: Use `PRAGMA synchronous;` to get the results. Note that the result is numeric e.g **0** = **Off** etc as per the documentation. I don't believe that tables existing or not matter. rather that no transactions must be incomplete. But best to use as soon as possible after opening the connection.

Comment: I use sqlite3_step on a prepared statement of "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;", but it returns SQLITE_DONE instead of SQLITE_ROW, which means there are no data returned. I also try it in sqlite3 shell but also returns nothing.

Comment: @alancc read the comment e.g. `sql = "PRAGMA synchronous;";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db,sql,callback,0,&zErrMsg);` results in ***synchronous = 2*** (i.e. values in the **synchronous** column is **2** which equates to NORMAL (in this case)).  As opposed to *`sql = "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db,sql,callback,0,&zErrMsg);`* which **does not** return result column synchronous. Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Comment: Basically best to try without any parameters/values/settings to query status/value and only provide parameter/value/setting when changing (not sure that the rule is 100% bullet proof though).